# Shared Element list changes

Tags: android, list, android-activity, element, shared

Activity A contains a list of images. Activity B contains the selected image. Using shared elements it successfully animates the image being moved to the new activity and back again when I finish B.

The problem is when the list is changed and I am on B, the image will try to go back to the same spot in the list. If it was the 10th item in the list when I selected it, then when I press back there are only 3 images in the list now it will throw an exception as that 10th list item container won't exist anymore. If I select the 1st list image, but whilst on B the list grows and my item is forced to the 5th spot in the list, when I press back it will still go back to that 1st list item it came from.

Is there a way I can tell it to move to a different list item on its return transition? (Activity B is informed when the list changes, so I do have the option to get it's new position)

Any suggestions would be great guys.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should only refresh your list when your ActivityA is ready.

Maybe you can use [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) in ActivityA to start ActivityB, though I'm unsure about the exactly life-cycle callbacks of ActivityA when ActivityB returns.

Maybe you should look into [SharedElementCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SharedElementCallback.html) and refresh your list when the transition has completed.